# White Spaces issue while converting to binary

Tags: python-3.x

I'm implementing A5/1 algorithm, I have the following function:

```
def to_binary(plain):
    print(plain)
    binary = str(''.join(format(ord(x), 'b') for x in plain))
    j = len(binary)
    binary_values = []
    k = 0
    while(k < j):
        binary_values.insert(k,int(binary[k]))
        k = k + 1
    return(binary_values)
```

then I'm reading the input as the following:

```
plainText = input("Please enter your plaintext : ")
print ("You entered : "+ plainText)
plainText = to_binary(plainText)
```

After that I generate a keyStream and I store it in a list, then I obtain the ciphered text as the following:

```
while(i < len(plainText)):
        cipherText = cipherText + str(plainText[i] ^ keyStream[i])
        i = i + 1
```

Now I can decrypt the ciphered text using the following function:

```
def decrypt(cipher,keystream):
    s = ""
    binary = []
    i = 0
    while(i<len(cipher)):
        binary.insert(i,int(cipher[i]))
        s = s + str(binary[i]^keystream[i])
        i = i +1
    print(s)
    return convert_binary_to_str(s)
```

and the `convert_binary_to_str` function is:

```
def convert_binary_to_str(bin_data):
    str_data =' '
    for i in range(0, len(bin_data), 7): 
        temp_data = bin_data[i:i + 7] 
        decimal_data = BinaryToDecimal(temp_data) 
        str_data = str_data + chr(decimal_data)  
    return str_data
```

Everything is working fine if the input was a sentence with no white spaces, but if the sentence was for example "Hello There", the decryption is corrupted because the white space representation in binary this way is taking "6 bits" while the other alphabetical characters are "7-bits" long, what can I do to solve this?? I need to store the plain text in a list to apply the algorithm.